# How do I make an aggregate on an integer with a grouped column, for which I only want some included?

Tags: sql, postgresql, business-intelligence

I have a table `prices` holding all prices that some products have had:

```
CREATE TABLE prices (
  id INT,
  product_id INT, /*Foreign key*/
  created_at TIMESTAMP,
  price INT
);
```

The first entity for a product_id is it's initial sales price. If the product is then reduced, a new entity will be added.

I would like to find the **mean and total price change per day across all products**.

This is some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO prices (id, product_id, created_at, price) VALUES (1, 1, '2020-01-01', 11000);
INSERT INTO prices (id, product_id, created_at, price) VALUES (2, 2, '2020-01-01', 3999);
INSERT INTO prices (id, product_id, created_at, price) VALUES (3, 3, '2020-01-01', 9999);
INSERT INTO prices (id, product_id, created_at, price) VALUES (4, 4, '2020-01-01', 2000);
INSERT INTO prices (id, product_id, created_at, price) VALUES (5, 1, '2020-01-02', 9999);
INSERT INTO prices (id, product_id, created_at, price) VALUES (6, 2, '2020-01-02', 2999);    
INSERT INTO prices (id, product_id, created_at, price) VALUES (7, 5, '2020-01-02', 2999);
INSERT INTO prices (id, product_id, created_at, price) VALUES (8, 1, '2020-01-03', 8999);
INSERT INTO prices (id, product_id, created_at, price) VALUES (9, 1, '2020-01-03 10:00:00', 7000);
INSERT INTO prices (id, product_id, created_at, price) VALUES (10, 5, '2020-01-03', 4000);
INSERT INTO prices (id, product_id, created_at, price) VALUES (11, 6, '2020-01-03', 3999);
INSERT INTO prices (id, product_id, created_at, price) VALUES (12, 3, '2020-01-03', 6999);
```

The expected result should be:

```
date       mean_price_change    total_price_change
2020-01-01 0                    0
2020-01-02 1000.5               2001
2020-01-03 1666                 4998
```

**Explanation:**

- Mean price reduction and total on '2020-01-01' was 0 as all products were new on that date.
- On '2020-01-02' however the mean price change was: (11000-9999 + 3999-2999)/2 = 1000.5 as both product_id `1` and `2` has been reduced to 9999 and 2999 on that day, and their previous prices were 11000 and 3999 and there total reduction would be: (11000-9999 + 3999-2999) = 2001.
- On '2020-01-03' only product_id `1`, `3` and `5` were changed. `1` at two different times on the day: 9999 => 8999 => 7000 (last one governing) and `3`: going from 9999 => 6999 a then `5`: going up from 2999 => 4000. This gives a total of: (9999-7000 + 9999-6999 + 2999-4000) = 4998 and a mean price reduction on that day of: 1666

I have added the data here too: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tJgoKFMJxcyg5gLDZMEP77/1

I stated to play around with some `DISTINCT ON` but that does not seem to do it...

Comment: You have two prices for the same product on the same date, which I find confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want `lag()` and aggregation:

```
select created_at, avg(prev_price - price), sum(prev_price - price)
from (select p.*, lag(price) over (partition by product_id order by created_at) as prev_price
      from prices p
     ) p
group by created_at
order by created_at;
```

You have two prices for product 1 on 2020-01-03.  Once I fix that, I get the same results as in your question.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=35c0f25192bf181168c063606940e2e8) is the db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

To handle multiple prices per day:

```
select created_at, avg(prev_price - price), sum(prev_price - price)
from (select p.*, lag(price) over (partition by product_id order by created_at) as prev_price
      from (select distinct on (product_id, created_at::date) p.*
            from prices p
            order by product_id, created_at::date
           ) p
     ) p
group by created_at
order by created_at;
```

Comment: It is possible to have multiple price changes on the same date. In fact the created_at is a timestamp, so you can say the "last" price change on the particular day (by timestamp) is the "governing" one. Can you incorporate that?

Comment: awesome answer Gordon! @NielsKristian you can use another subquery to eliminate the irrelvant rows: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=94aeb6b035eb3abec7ac81a0bf58143d

Comment: @NielsKristian . . . Yes.  You can just keep one record per day before using `lag()`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select 
created_at, 
avg(change),
sum(change)
from
(
    with cte as 
    (
    select 
    id, 
    product_id,
    created_at,
    lag(created_at) over(order by product_id, created_at) as last_date,
    price
    from prices
    )
    select
    c.id,
    c.product_id,
    c.created_at,
    c.last_date,
    p.price as last_price,
    c.price,
    COALESCE(p.price - c.price,0) as change
    from cte c
    left join prices p on c.product_id =p.product_id  and c.last_date =p.created_at
  where p.price != c.price or p.price is null
) tmp
group by created_at
order by created_at
```

Comment: Sorry, I was not explicit enough about the type of `created_at` column. It's actually a `TIMESTAMP`

Comment: And what's the problem whith it?

Answer (score 0):

The query below tracks all price changes, notice that we join current and earlier based on

- their product being the same
- earlier is indeed earlier than current
- earlier is the latest item on a date earlier than current
- current is the latest item on its own date

`select today.product_id, (today.price - coalesce(earlier.price)), today.created_at as difference
    from prices current
    join prices earlier
    on today.product_id = earlier.product_id and earlier.created_at < current.created_at
    where not exists (
        select 1
        from prices later
        where later.product_id = today.product_id and
        (
         ((today.created_at = later.created_at) and (today.id < later.id)) or
         ((earlier.created_at <= later.created_at) and (earlier.id < later.id))
        )
    );`

Now, let's do some aggregation:

```
select created_at, avg(today.price - coalesce(earlier.price)) as mean, sum(today.price - coalesce(earlier.price)) as total
from prices current
left join prices earlier
on today.product_id = earlier.product_id and earlier.created_at < current.created_at
where not exists (
    select 1
    from prices later
    where later.product_id = today.product_id and
    (
     ((today.created_at = later.created_at) and (today.id < later.id)) or
     ((earlier.created_at <= later.created_at) and (earlier.id < later.id))
    )
)
group by created_at
order by created_at;
```

Comment: Hmm I can't seem to get this to work? Also I updated the question with the right type for `created_at` (timestamp). Sorry for that

Comment: @NielsKristian this can be non-functional, since this was never tested. Can you point out what the error is? Even better: can you create a SQL Fiddle?